# How can i make my application to display in different languages using android

Tags: android

I have an application that is running but i want to be able to change it to different languages like spanish and italian.please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read  [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) article to learn more about it

Comment: guys please can you show me a small example because those article in localization only shows example with pictures so please show me example with text.

Comment: take a look at [Hello, L10N](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html#localize_strings)

Answer (score 2):

In your project, add a "values-es" directory in the "res" directory. Then put a new file "string.xml" in this directory.You should now have a "string.xml" file in the "values" directory and a "string.xml" file in the "values-es" directory.

Now, you just have to put in EACH file something like that:

In the "string.xml" of the "values" directory:

```
<resources>
    <string name="toto">The value in the default language</string>
</resources>
```

In the "string.xml" of the "values-es" directory:

```
<resources>
    <string name="toto">The value in spanish</string>
</resources>
```

Now, in your code, when you'll call the "toto" string, it will choose the one in the right language.

Comment: thanx but when i run my application it automatically choses the one in values so my last question is how can i make it to be able to use the string in values-es?

Comment: If your phone is in "es" language, it will AUTOMATICALLY choose the value in the "values-es" file

Comment: I do get your Answer but the problem I have ,I dont know how to call the String resources to the Emulator, to change the language while the app is running

Comment: If you change language WHILE the app is running, you'll have to relaunch for the changes to take effect.

Comment: can you please tell me the code behind the button that is supposed to cahange the language or show me steps how to do it please

Comment: You change the language of your device by using the native parameters. "Menu/Parameters/Languages & Country" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a string.xml in "values-it" and "values-es" directories. The device will automatically use the resources corresponding to the device's language. One thing you have to know about it, is that the "values" directory will be used by default. So here's the behaviour if I have a "values" and a "values-es" directories: hen you'll launch your app, the device will check if its language is "es". If it's the case, it will use the "values-es" resources. In ALL the other cases, it will use the "values" directory.